# Build embeddable HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I'm new to HTML5

I'm trying make my basic paint/whiteboard webpage embeddable to any other website.

The whiteboard consist of three files: index.html, app.js and style.css

what I'm asking for is how to make it more like widget to be embeddable any where?

I have did many searches and get really confused, between building jQuery widget like this
http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/#loading-javascript-libraries

or I don't have to as there are many separate files?

any recommendation and guidance would be highly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Well, if anyone places an iframe with src=[your webpage's URL] in their website, your page would already be showing there. Seems to be quite enough for what you want.

Comment: if you don't want a frame, you can put the html and css inside your js file as a string.

Comment: @dandavis, can you provide any link or example on how to do that? is it related by any meaning to jQuery plugin or widget?

Comment: css example: `$("head").append($("<style>").html("   body{ color:red}  "))`; to turn your css into a string literal, you can go to https://danml.com/slim, paste your code in IN, and choose Apply Engine>JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer here depends on your target audience.

@lucasnadalutti is correct that an iFrame may be the most universally accepted way to embed an entire HTML page, but if that page needs to interact with the host site's other elements, data, or server in any way, you'll probably want to pursue another approach.

Since you're creating a widget that is meant to be embedded in other people's websites, your target audience is probably other developers, since they will be the ones who might choose to use your widget on the sites they build.

Assuming that developers are your target audience for the widget, you could create a WordPress plugin, a jQuery plugin, or any number of other framework-specific plugins that make it easy for developers to use your code.

The choice is really yours as to what framework to create it for, and that decision is probably based on the place you think the demand for that type of widget would be highest...

But if you're just stating out, I'd recommend creating a jQuery plugin with a public GitHub repo with a well-written README to explain how to use the widget.

Here's a good example:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

**EDIT**
Per your comment, here are some resources and examples more specific to your needs:

Here'a good resource for how to build a jQuery plugin:
https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Owl Carousel is a good example of a jQuery plugin that requires HTML, CSS, and JS files. 
See this link for an example of how to implement the plugin:
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#demo

**Page setup + CSS:**

```
<!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">

<!-- Default Theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">

<!--  jQuery 1.7+  -->
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include js plugin -->
<script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  <div> Your Content </div>
  ...
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();

 });
```

Comment: Now I get that the webpage which I will use my widget in may use webrtc and web-sockets, so iFrame might cause some security issue because of  same origin policy or will have to update crossdomain file which I don't like to do.

I have to go through jQuery UI widget, do you have good reference to follow, and how I will combine my three files "HTML, JS, CSS" compined in one file to make it more like widget call??